# Using iterations (or some other method) to apply a function across a dataframe and tabulate multiple output values

Tags: python, function, pandas, loops

I have a function that needs to be mapped across a dataframe to every cell in columns B, C.  For each cell input, the function outputs 4 variables which I would like to track, as well as the ID in column A and the column from which the iteration acted on.

```
def function(cell):
   add_2 = cell + 2
   subtract_2 = cell - 2
   multiply_2 = cell*2
   divide_2  = cell/2
```

For example:

```
df
[A]     [B]     [C]
AAA     2       4
BBB     6       10
```

Goal Output:

```
df2
[ID]    [COL]   [Add_2]   [Subtract_2]   [Multiply_2]    [Divide_2]
AAA     B       4          0             4               1   
AAA     C       6          2             8               2
BBB     B       8          4             12              3
BBB     C       12         8             20              5
```

I've explored the option of passing a for loop iteration and populate an empty dataframe through the `.append()` method, but I cannot seem to get the proper for loop to output what I'm looking for.  I also read into the `.applymap()` means to iterate across a dataframe, but I haven't found a way to tabulate my output dataframe.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to getting your target output:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='A', var_name='COL', value_name='VAL')
val = df['VAL']
df.assign(
  Add_2 = val.add(2),
  Subtract_2 = val.sub(2),
  Multiply_2 = val.mul(2),
  Divide_2 = val.div(2)
).drop('VAL', axis=1)

#    [A]  COL  Add_2  Divide_2  Multiply_2  Subtract_2
# 0  AAA  [B]      4       1.0           4           0
# 1  BBB  [B]      8       3.0          12           4
# 2  AAA  [C]      6       2.0           8           2
# 3  BBB  [C]     12       5.0          20           8
```

... and here's how you can write that into a function that takes an arbitrary `num` argument, rather than just `2`:

```
def function(dframe, num):

  # here, "melt" returns 3 columns: [A], COL, value
  temp_df = dframe.melt(id_vars='[A]', var_name='COL')

  # store the base column for the calculations,
  # so we only look it up once
  val = temp_df['value']

  # store the num argument as a string,
  # so we can add column suffixes
  str_num = str(num)

  # create a dict of column names + transformed Series objects
  # to pass into "assign"
  transformations = {
    ("Add_" + str_num): val.add(num),
    ("Subtract_" + str_num): val.sub(num),
    ("Multiply_" + str_num): val.mul(num),
    ("Divide_" + str_num): val.div(num)
    }
  return temp_df.assign(**transformations).drop('value', axis=1)

# example:
function(df, 10)
#    [A]  COL  Add_10  Divide_10  Multiply_10  Subtract_10
# 0  AAA  [B]      12        0.2           20           -8
# 1  BBB  [B]      16        0.6           60           -4
# 2  AAA  [C]      14        0.4           40           -6
# 3  BBB  [C]      20        1.0          100            0
```